# Text input has focus but doesn't update what I type until after I scroll

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with an HTML5 video. When I open the Bootstrap modal login dialog with the page scrolled to zero, everything works as expected. When I scroll down the page or open the dialog after scrolling, the username and password input boxes sort of freeze: I can enter text but I won't see it until after I scroll again. The blinky caret will also freeze unless I'm scrolling around the page. If I remove the video tag then everything works fine. This only happens in Chrome (I'm using Version 38.0.2125.104 m). I'm also using AngularJS.

Have any of you encountered a problem like this?

Comment: I've been having a similar problem (though I'm not using Angular, nor do I have any videos on the page). I have an `input` element whose text won't update until I scroll (Chrome only). This may be something wrong with Chrome's rendering, but adding the usual `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` sorted it for me.

Comment: The problem just went away for me when I merged another coders changes into mine. I still don't know what caused it.